# Program's window closes after using ToastNotifier (win10toast)

Tags: python, datetime, time, pyqt5, notify

recently I faced with the problem. There is reminder which notifies about somesthing in some period of time. I use Python 3.7 and PyQt5 for creating interface. Also, there is library which is named "win10toast" and module "ToastNotifer" for notifying. After entering data (time and text for reminder) and clicking submitting button, Window just closes, but sometimes window's title changes to "program do not answer" and after 2-3 seconds window closes too. I think, that it is connected with win10toast. I need program no to close, because after using reminder user can go back and open notepad or just write his|her mark there. That is problem, which i can not solve.  I do not know why it happens. Reminder's code starts from the class fileush till the closing fragment. You have to download zip file from my github, because there is main python and ui(interface) programs. Please install library win10toast and import ToastNotifier also, datetime in order to know the current time. Thanks) Link to my github is in the end of question

My code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPlainTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTimeEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
import time
from datetime import datetime

class fileush(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()

        uic.loadUi('ui_fileush.ui', self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.running)

    def running(self):
        toaster = ToastNotifier()
        self.now = datetime.now()
        self.tmf = self.tm.time()
        self.uak = self.tmf.toString()
        self.current_time = self.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        self.seku = self.current_time.split(":")
        self.seku2 = self.uak.split(":")
        self.seknot = 3600 * (int(self.seku2[0])) + (int(self.seku2[1])) * 60
        self.sekcur = 3600 * (int(self.seku[0])) + (int(self.seku[1])) * 60 + (int(self.seku[2]))

        if self.sekcur >= self.seknot:
            self.label_5.setText('ERROR')

        else:
            self.label_5.setText('')
            self.secs = 3600 * (int(self.seku2[0]) - int(self.seku[0])) + 60 * (int(self.seku2[1]) - int(self.seku[1])) - int(self.seku[2])
            self.second_input = self.lineEdit_2.text()
            t = time.sleep(int(self.secs))
            toaster.show_toast(self.second_input)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = fileush()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Link to my github: https://github.com/iMAGA07/reminder

Comment: "Window tries to close and show the error". What error?

Comment: I do not know how to explain it for you. Sorry, could you download it and try it yourself?

Comment: Also, i corrected my previous question as you said.

Comment: I can't test it as I don't use Windows 10. Please find some way to try to explain it, as it might be useful to other users too.

Comment: ok, after entering data (time and text for reminder) and clicking submitting button, Window just closes, but sometimes window's title changes to "program do not answer" and after 2-3 seconds window closes too. I think, that it is connected with win10toast. I need program no to close, because after using reminder user can go back and open notepad or just write his|her mark there. That is problrm, which i can not solve. Thanks

Comment: Ok, if that's the case, it really seems that the issue is about toaster (it might not be a PyQt related question at all) and I can't help you; but I suggest you to incorporate what you wrote in your last comment directly in the question. Also, try creating a *new example from scratch*, with just the basic elements needed to test and find the source of your problem; if you're lucky, you'll find your solution (in that case, add your own answer and mark it as accepted), if the problem still exists, you can use *that* new minimal and smaller example for your question instead.

Comment: Create a minimal reproducible example which will easy to test and help you....https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have already done it. Problem is connected with reminder only in pyqt5. I think it is not difficullt to undersatnd the program.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I used a thread to solve it.

If you are not familiar with threads, they basically help you to run different functions at the same time, the code that I have written is:

```
import threading

thread = threading.Thread(target=self.noti)
thread.start()

def noti(self):
    h = ToastNotifier()
    h.show_toast("TODO UPDATE", f"Hurry up, you have less than 3 days to finish the task you had set {task}!!", )
```

Here I was trying to make a todo application which gives a notification when there is less than 3 days to finish the task they had set.